# How do I configure CI hudson with PHPunit and how do I run phpunit using hudson?

Tags: hudson, phpunit

I am getting following error mentioned below. Help is much needed for this...
kindly go through the errors.

Started by an SCM change

```
Updating https://suppliesguys.unfuddle.com/svn/suppliesguys_frontend2/Frontend-Texity/src
U         sites\all\modules\print\print_pdf\print_pdf.pages.inc
At revision 1134
[workspace] $ sh -xe C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson6292587174545072503.sh
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "E:\Projects\Hudson\.hudson\jobs\TSG\workspace"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
 at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:149)
 at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:121)
 at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:636)
 at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:271)
 at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:278)
 at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:83)
 at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:58)
 at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:584)
 at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.build(Build.java:174)
 at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.doRun(Build.java:138)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:416)
 at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1244)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:122)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
 ... 17 more
Publishing Javadoc
Publishing Clover coverage report...
No Clover report will be published due to a Build Failure
[xUnit] Starting to record.
[xUnit] [PHPUnit] - Use the embedded style sheet.
[xUnit] [ERROR] - No test report file(s) were found with the pattern 'build/logs/phpunit.xml' relative to 'E:\Projects\Hudson\.hudson\jobs\TSG\workspace' for the testing framework 'PHPUnit'.  Did you enter a pattern relative to the correct directory?  Did you generate the result report(s) for 'PHPUnit'?
[xUnit] Stopping recording.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a couple of problems:

```
FATAL: command execution failed java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "E:\Projects\Hudson.hudson\jobs\TSG\workspace"):
```

The user that's running the Hudson job doesn't have the "sh" command in its path, so it can't run shell scripts.  Adding /bin to the $PATH of the Hudson user should fix this.

```
[xUnit] [ERROR] - No test report file(s) were found with the pattern 'build/logs/phpunit.xml' relative to 'E:\Projects\Hudson.hudson\jobs\TSG\workspace' for the testing framework 'PHPUnit'.
```

This is probably a result of the previous error; the build just didn't get far enough to run the PHPUnit tests.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the "Execute shell" build step on a windows system instead of the "Execute Windows batch command" build step. Windows doesn't normally have 'sh', so the former won't work.

Answer (score 0):

'sh' is for linux implementations. Both '.exe' and 'bat' files are used in windows. Are you trying to setup and run Hudson on windows or linux?